# What does removing a Fragment in Android really do?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

What impact does removing a Fragment in Android have on the performance of an application. What I am referring to is something like:

```
fragmentTransaction.remove(myFragment);
```

I've read the documentation about the Fragment Lifecycle [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and the description of the remove method in the Fragment Transaction [Fragment Transaction remove()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#remove(android.app.Fragment)) but haven't found whether calling the remove actually frees the memory occupied the Fragment's views.

Also, is there a way that I can suspend Fragments into a low memory state? The idea is that in an application with many Fragments and assuming that only one Fragment is visible at a time, is there anything I can do to optimize memory?

Answer (score 1):

Your app should be optimized for best performance from design. It should not change it's behavior upon system resources. If you are low on memory, the background apps are killed so that your app can run smoothly and you user can get **the best** of it.

Just use a fragment when you need it. And remove it when it's not needed. If you do it the right way, you're already optimizing your app.

Comment: Thanks. But what I really need to know is does removing a fragment really do any good? And if so what does it do? This will help me to make a decision on when to remove a fragment.

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that it doesn't matter. Your UX should decide whether to remove or not a fragment. Not your system resources. You can't hide information from your user just because you think your are low on memory.

Comment: By design of the app the information I.e. the previous fragment is not needed any more. But the user may at a later stage choose to navigate to that fragment again. In this case, will it really be helpful to destroy the fragment? Or can I just keep it in the back stack and restore it when needed?

Comment: In this case you should always keep it in the back stack. The Android system is already designed the handle this case.